# SMS Intent Not working In Android on loop

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created android service which sends intent to SMS app

here is my SMS intent code

```
log("MessageOperation","${phoneNumber}-${message}")
val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:$phoneNumber"))
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message)
smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(smsIntent)
```

Below I have provided my service class method which loops one by one

```
private fun sendMessagesCoroutine(messageList: List<SMS>, position: Int) {
    if(position != messageList.size){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            delay(2000)
            messageList[position].let { message ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    openDefaultSmsApp(message.mobileNumber, message.message!!)
                    sendMessagesCoroutine(messageList, position+1)
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        stopSelf()
    }
}
```

Now when I check logs it's working fine but SMS app opens only for 3-4 messages then it gets stoped for new messages for new number.
sometime it gets stop on first intent itself

what to do with this android mess.

Comment: Starting an activity to send an SMS message is designed for doing that just once, not in a loop. You will need to wait until the user has dealt with the first message before trying to send the second (e.g., wait until `ProcessLifecycleOwner` reports that your UI has started again).

Comment: Great. Now I have to implement another solution for this task

Comment: Why are you launching the sms app? There are ways to send an SMS programmatically, without launching any `Activity`. See `SmsManager`.

Comment: Google is not providing sms permission for non default SMS app. And my app is for management purpose of some educational data Here is link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?hl=en